# convergence and holomorphic function - explanations and proofs

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I haven't had analysis for a long time and I've forgotten plenty.

Could you please explain me and prove that the following converges:

$$
\sum_{n \geq 1}e^{-n^2t\pi}, t>0 c
$$
and explain why the following function is holomorphic on $\text{Re}(s)>0$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{s-1}dt
$$

Comment: for 1.) you can look up the integration criteria
for 2.) you should anlayse the behaviour for small $t$ because thats the only critical region

Comment: @tired could you please provide further explanations?